# How to copy a selected row from dataframe from existing dataframe on conditional check? [python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

### The Scenario

I have dataframe `df1` which needs to cutdown into different dataframes based on a list `y_km`.
Dataframe `df1` holds data as follows:

```
          0         1         2
0  3.000000  4.000000  3.000000   
1  3.618555  3.646074  3.923834   
2  2.669256  2.769302  2.897346
3  4.340775  4.311200  4.341143
```

and `y_km` as `[0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]`

### My Snippet

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(X)
df1 = df1.iloc[0:5,:10]
cl0 = pd.DataFrame()
cl1 = pd.DataFrame()
cl2 = pd.DataFrame()
cl3 = pd.DataFrame()

y_km = list(y_kmeans)
for i in y_kmeans:
    rows = df1.iloc[i, :]
    if i == 0:
        cl0 = cl0.append(rows, ignore_index=False)
    elif i == 1:
        cl1 = cl1.append(rows, ignore_index=False)
    elif i == 2:
        cl2 = cl2.append(rows, ignore_index=False)
    elif i == 3:
        cl3 = cl3.append(rows, ignore_index=False)
```

Issue with this is, that my clX DFrames are having the same records as of first inserted.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are the indices in df1 repeated? Thus are you trying to divide the df by label based index values? Having trouble understand your use case. If you are using iloc, then you are trying to grab elements by integer based indexing (rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `.groupby`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (13, 3)))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
     0   1   2
0   73  85  15
1    4  56   5
2   30  74   1
3   93  16   9
4   94  97  41
5   37  49  63
6   28  66  10
7   74  35   4
8    1  76  65
9    5  79  27
10  54  33  74
11  99  54  46
12  67  28  77
```

Simply:

```
In [5]: y_km = [0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]

In [6]: dfs = {k:g for k,g in df.groupby(y_km)}
```

Now, I've gone ahead and put the data-frames in a `dict`, but you can do whatever you want. I suggest against a bunch of variables, and rather, keep things together in a container of some sort. Note:

```
In [7]: dfs[0]
Out[7]:
     0   1   2
0   73  85  15
10  54  33  74

In [8]: dfs[1]
Out[8]:
     0   1   2
3   93  16   9
8    1  76  65
9    5  79  27
11  99  54  46

In [9]: dfs[3]
Out[9]:
    0   1   2
1   4  56   5
5  37  49  63
6  28  66  10
7  74  35   4

In [10]: dfs[2]
Out[10]:
     0   1   2
2   30  74   1
4   94  97  41
12  67  28  77
```

Comment: So let's say, I store dfs[0] into another dataframe (say cl0), that'll work fine too right? Since I need to generate csv files out of it.

Comment: @T3J45 Huh? You want to store a data-frame in a dataframe? That sounds... inadvisable. Note: `dfs[0]` **is a data-frame** and if you want to save a csv, just do `dfs[0].to_csv('first_frame.csv')`

Comment: What's the possible harm that would do?

Comment: @T3J45 Well for starters, putting a data-frame inside another data-frame will almost certainly not produce the csv you want. It simply makes no sense, unless I am not understanding you